Vertical grid with banners that span all columns using compose
Using Compose to create a 3 column vertical list, but from time to time i need to insert a component that spans across all 3 columns, like a banner that fills the entire width of the screen. I am positive there should be a best practice way of doing this, but I can't seem to find it.
Any ideas ?

You can use LazyVerticalGrid with custom GridItemSpan for your items. For regular items use 1, for banner use number that matches column count:
Simple example of how to use spans:
//Total column count fro the grid
val columnCount = 3

//Dummy data
val items = remember { listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) }

LazyVerticalGrid(
columns = GridCells.Fixed(columnCount),
horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 10.dp),
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 10.dp)
) {

    //Regular items
    items(
        items = items,
        span = { item -> GridItemSpan(currentLineSpan = 1) }
    ) { item ->
        Text(
            text = item.toString(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }

    //Full width banner item
    item(
        span = { GridItemSpan(currentLineSpan = columnCount) }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(80.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {

            Text(
                text = "Banner",
                modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}

Since you need it from time to time, i would recommend you find way how to provide lineSpan based on the data, i prefer using sealed classes for this:
Example Data class:
//Using sealed class for items
sealed class Item constructor(
    val lineSpan: Int
) {
    //For reguar items set smaller span
    class Category(val name: String) : Item(lineSpan = 1)

    //For full width items set same span as column count
    class Banner(val text: String) : Item(lineSpan = 3)
}

And composable:
//Total column count fro the grid
val columnCount = 3
//Dummy data
val items = remember {
    listOf(
        Item.Category(name = "Favorites"),
        Item.Category(name = "Most popular"),
        Item.Category(name = "Most rated"),
        Item.Banner(text = "Banner 1"),
        Item.Category(name = "Comedy"),
        Item.Category(name = "Action"),
        Item.Category(name = "Drama"),
        Item.Banner(text = "Banner 2"),
    )
}

LazyVerticalGrid(
columns = GridCells.Fixed(columnCount),
horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 10.dp),
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 10.dp)
) {

    //Regular items
    items(
        items = items,
        //Setting line span based on data item
        span = { item -> GridItemSpan(currentLineSpan = item.lineSpan) }
    ) { item ->
        when (item) {
            is Item.Category -> {
                Text(
                    text = item.name,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }

            is Item.Banner-> {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(height = 80.dp)
                        .background(color = Color.Red)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = item.text,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        color = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

With this you are able to combine data items with the banners.
